# Magento: how to remove paragraphs around Widgets

Tags: magento, widget, paragraph

I'm new to magento and I just put a widget in a cms page. After having a look at the source code I saw a surrounding p-tag around the widget. Is there a way to remove it without disabling the wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on template hints in admin.

Assuming this is the template that the widget renders:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\cms\widget\static_block\default.phtml

Copy this template to:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\cms\widget\static_block\default.phtml

Replace the code from:

```
<div class="widget widget-static-block"><?php echo $this->getText(); ?></div>
```

to:

```
<div class="widget widget-static-block"><?php echo strip_tags( $this->getText() ); ?></div>
```

You can customize allowed html tags by including a second parameter:

> https://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
Unfortunately the p tag isn't rendered within the widget. The p tag surrounds the widget. :(